# What is the best invisible character can I use to replace &nbsp;?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, reporting, telerik, special-characters

I use some telerik report to print some report.

I need to use Telerik.Reporting.TextBox to print labels.

Some labels are stock in .txt files, like "   Apple".

When I see a label with spaces, it means I have to indent it in the report, so in the TextBox.

The thing is when we export the report in pdf, we have the indentation, but not when we see in the browser. If I replace the spaces by "& nbsp;", we see the indentation in the browser, but when exporting to pdf, we see the "& nbsp;".

One way to do this is to use HtmlTextBox, so both the browser and the export works fine, but we have other constraints that says we must keep the TextBox.

My idea is to replace the spaces by a blank character, an invisble one, like alt+0160, but there is a lot of choice, and I want the one that will work in any browser, any export (TIFF, PDF, Excel...).

Is someone have a good clue about this choice ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Unicode code point U+00A0 (non-breaking space), which is what the entity `&nbsp;` represents.  How this should be encoded in your document depends on the character set in use.

Comment: It's funny the solution I propose is the same as yours (I just see that alt+0160 = U+00A0)

Comment: @Scorpi0: Just make sure you are encoding it properly in the document.

Comment: So other users don't have to hunt for it from here, here's one way to do this Unicode character replace in C#: `text = text.Replace(' ', '\u00A0');`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `&nbsp;` with `""`