# How do I keep leading spaces in an asp.net textbox

Tags: asp.net

i have a text-box web control that automatically trims any leading spaces in it's content thus when i get the text it is not the same as what the user had initially written (in case he entered a leading space)

is there is a way to disable this feature

Comment: Firstly,is there any `.trim()` in your code? secondly, please show any code you are currently using to try do this.

Comment: no there is no .trim() i think that this is a feature in asp:TextBox control it trims any leading spaces

Comment: i've never had that error.... been using asp.net for 3 years.. thats why i queried it

Comment: Are you saving the value to SQL Server? If so, make sure the db isn't automatically trimming out the witespace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well there is only one solution to override the default behavior of that  is that you write a javascript function that assigns whicever the user enters to a Hidden field and then you capture the value of that hidden field in your button or whatever postback event you have

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" onkeydown="document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value += this.value" ></asp:TextBox>
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the blank spaces with `&nbsp;` html.

E.g

```
Dim TextWithSpaces As String = OriginalText.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;")

TextBox.Text = TextWithSpaces
```

Comment: thanks Ryan but i think this won't work in case the user enters a leading space in the textbox how then could i capture the '&nbsp' if it is already trimed

Comment: You don't bind the text to the textbox until you've done the replace first, if you know what I mean?

Comment: i think you are handling a server-side text i am talking about a client side text which the user entered

Answer (score 0):

Actually there might be another workaround for this. ASP.NET aims to replace `U+0020` (Unicode code point for `space`) but it doesn't do that for some other whitespace characters, for instance `U+00A0` - `no-break space`.

I had the problem with repeating space character that needed to be preserved on ASP.NET page in a `RadTextBox` (which behaved like ordinary ASP `TextBox` when it came to keeping whitespace which means I lost all but one repeating space).

So, if you set text like this:

```
txtName.Text = name.Replace(' ', '\u00A0');
```

and you get text from textbox like this:

```
name = txtName.Text.Replace('\u00A0', ' ');
```

for user it is going to look like there are spaces inside textbox and ASP.NET is not going to remove these space-like characters.

Answer was inspired by this answer: [What is the best invisible character can I use to replace &nbsp;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488359/what-is-the-best-invisible-character-can-i-use-to-replace-nbsp)