# How to keep spaces with escape sequences stringbuilder c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, whitespace, ansi-escape

I have a `stringbuilder` setup with escape sequences to show a ASCII like art to text. I am using ASP.NET Web Forms. Here is my code:

```
sb.AppendLine(@"   _____ ______   ___  ___  ________                                        ");
sb.AppendLine(@"  |\   _ \  _   \|\  \|\  \|\   ___ \                                       ");
sb.AppendLine(@"  \ \  \\\__\ \  \ \  \\\  \ \  \_|\ \                                      ");
sb.AppendLine(@"   \ \  \\|__| \  \ \  \\\  \ \  \ \\ \                                     ");
sb.AppendLine(@"    \ \  \    \ \  \ \  \\\  \ \  \_\\ \                                    ");
sb.AppendLine(@"     \ \__\    \ \__\ \_______\ \_______\                                   ");
sb.AppendLine(@"      \|__|     \|__|\|_______|\|_______|                                   ");
sb.AppendLine(@"                                                                            ");
```

And here is the output:

```
 _____ ______ ___ ___ ________ 
 |\ _ \ _ \|\ \|\ \|\ ___ \ 
 \ \ \\\__\ \ \ \ \\\ \ \ \_|\ \ 
 \ \ \\|__| \ \ \ \\\ \ \ \ \\ \ 
 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \\\ \ \ \_\\ \ 
 \ \__\ \ \__\ \_______\ \_______\ 
 \|__| \|__|\|_______|\|_______|
```

I use a textbox to display my stringbuilder `textbox1.Text = sb.ToString();` and print it on an ASP.NET page.

How can I keep my strings just as I typed them?

Comment: Show how you generate the output also, might be pertinent to the issue.

Comment: I see no problem, what you typed is what you got. Yes, the output in SO in the question does not look the same but if you copy/paste your question text (seen in the Edit) to NotePad the 2 look exactly alike. So it probably just depends on what you are using to view that output.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, sorry just added that

Comment: Windows forms or WPF?

Comment: or is the output a webpage?

Comment: @igor His "output" is different than the code. His output has no more than 1 space in a row but his code has up to ~5 spaces in a row. nate needs to show us how he is generating the output, or how he is viewing it. StackOverflow comments for example strip extra white space (beyond 1 character), so maybe whatever he's "viewing" the text with is removing all but 1 space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep leading spaces in an asp.net textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667870/how-do-i-keep-leading-spaces-in-an-asp-net-textbox)

Comment: @Igor ASP.NET is what I am using

Comment: @Quantic - read my initial comment again and then hit the EDIT button on the question itself, you will see what I am talking about.

Comment: @igor I see, so SO is stripping the whitespace, I guess it's not just in comments like I said. Makes this question odd because he would have had to have copied it from a source that looks fine. Maybe he's viewing it with a highly variable-width font so it looks weird to begin with, then he pasted it into SO which stripped whitespace and made it look even worse.

Comment: NB: The spaces are preserved in a `string` in C# and also in a `StringBuilder` (it accept `strings`) - so this isn't a `StringBuilder` thing and I will remove the tag

Comment: "And here is the output" If this *is* the output, what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output is a html webpage, and in html multiple spaces are displayed as one space.

You could solve this with css:

```
.myTextBox{
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Or using the `<pre>` tag if this isn't and form element (`<input>`, `<textarea>` etc):

```
<div>multiple    spaces     will     be    displayed    as    one space</div>
<pre>multiple    spaces     will     be    displayed    as     typed! </pre>
```

Comment: I am trying this now

Comment: I couldn't get the css to work in the asp.net page for some reason, but I got the <pre> tag to work. I wish I could have gotten the css to work the tag makes a box around the textbox

Comment: If you will post the HTML code, it will be easier to help :)

Comment: in the page that the textbox is in:

Comment: <style type="text/css">
    .txtMain{
  white-space: pre;
}
</style>

Comment: The HTML of the texbox I mean (just edit your question)